# Why is vs code not working without any output in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i try to run any code in vs code it does not show anything in the terminal but when i try the same thing in pycharm or python it works just fine. What is causing the problem? No error or anything it just shows nothing new in terminal. It used to work fine.
edit: i solved it by deleting everything related to it and then reinstalling

Comment: Please add an example of what you're trying to do and the outcome

Comment: i dont remember the first thing i ran but when it didnt work i just wrote print('n') and it doesnt print it

Comment: but on other apps it works fine

Comment: What language, python? Please add the appropriate tag.